# Find count of entries that were correct all days

Tags: php, mysql

I have a contest where people answer a question over the course of a month.

There is a question table with the answer ID and date, and an entry table where it saves their guess (answer ID) and date (along with their email address and/or site username).

I can see how many are correct per day with this:

```
SELECT e.day, count(e.eid) AS correct_entries
FROM question q, entry e 
WHERE q.year = '2016'
AND e.day = q.day
AND e.sid_guess = q.sid_answer
AND e.date_guess = q.answer_date
GROUP BY e.day
ORDER BY e.day
```

But I would like to know how many people get every day correct (by email address or username - sometimes username is not provided). Can anyone provide clues to how I would get this done?

I think it would be pretty easy to do it in php, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do in pure mysql.